# Will applying for a Dutch residence permit invalidate my French residence permit immediately?

Tags: france, resident-permit, netherlands, schengen, skilled-migration

I am a non-EEA citizen finishing my PhD soon in France and have an offer to join a company in the Netherlands.

My future Dutch employer informed me that I don't need to apply for a Dutch visa given that I am a resident of a Schengen country. They will apply for a residence permit on my behalf. If the application is accepted, my future employer will book an appointment for me and I will be able to travel to the Netherlands to finalize the application and get my passport stamped which will allow me to work until my residence card is issued.

While my future employer applies for the residence permit I might be outside France and the Schengen area. My question is: if the Dutch authorities accept the application submitted by my future employer (I will be outside France by then), will my French residence permit be invalidated? Will I be able to reenter the Schengen area?

Comment: 1. You can typically enter the Schengen area with a foreign passport regardless of your residence permit (of course, depending on which passport you hold), so I'd separate that part of the question. 2. Why would your French residence be invalidated?

Comment: I cannot enter the Schengen area with my passport, I need a visa or a residence permit. Currently I hold a French residence permit. It could be invalidated since it is not allowed to hold two resident permits in two different countries simultaneously, or at least that's what I read in different forums.

Comment: @Salah I don't think there is an explicit prohibition in EU law against having two residence permits in two Schengen countries.  Even if there were, it would be the *issue* of another permit that would invalidate your French one, not the application for one. The granting of residence permits is primarily governed by national law. French law could say that an application for a foreign residence permit renders a French permit invalid, but that is highly unlikely.  If you can provide a reference to any assertion that simultaneous permits are forbidden, please edit your question to add it.

Comment: @Salah: So link to where you've read this...

Comment: I've read it some time ago on a French website for legal counselling but unfortunately I am not able to find it again. After you raised these points, I would like to know myself if it is correct that simultaneous residence permits are not allowed.